# How to get user information in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, bots, discord

Recently, I'm creating a Discord bot that rolls dices. But, in order for this to work, I have to program every single dice. Like this:

```
const commando = require('discord.js-commando');

class TwentyDiceRollCommand extends commando.Command {
constructor(client) {
    super(client, {
        name: 'rolltwenty',
        group: 'random',
        memberName: 'rolltwenty',
        description: 'Rolls a twenty die'
    });
}

async run(message, args){
    var rollTwenty = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
    message.reply(' você tirou um ' + rollTwenty);
}
}

module.exports = TwentyDiceRollCommand;
```

What I have to do to make it work without pre-programming? Like, roll a d978 dice.

Comment: Pass a parameter that contains the number of faces of your die.

Comment: But how I make the user choose this?

Comment: By asking them, in the same way you ask them for anything else.